# How to make WPF Toolkit charts expand with to fit content?

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

I'm trying to create some bar charts from `DotNetProjects.Wpf.Toolkit` that display some data totals, though the data can change at run time.  The problem is that I cannot get the chart to fit the size of the content - I always have to provide a fixed value (and setting `Height="Auto"` doesn't work), but I don't know what the size will need to be while running.  What can I do to make my chart fit the content rather than the other way around?

My XAML code looks like this:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Movie_Vault"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=DotNetProjects.Layout.Toolkit" xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit" x:Class="Movie_Vault.frmStatistics"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="frmStatistics" Style="{StaticResource RoundedFormStyle}" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner">
    <Border Style="{StaticResource WindowBorderStyle}">
        <DockPanel x:Name="OuterPanel" >
            <Border Style="{StaticResource PanelBorderStyle}" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <DockPanel x:Name="TopPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Image Height="16" Margin="8,4,8,4" Source="Images/process.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MediumFont}"><Run Text="Statistics"/></TextBlock>
                    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Button x:Name="btnClose" Content="X" Style="{StaticResource MicroButtonStyle}" Margin="0,0,8,0" Click="btnClose_Click"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DockPanel>
            </Border>
            <Border Style="{StaticResource PanelBorderStyle}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="0,8,0,0">
                <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Top"  >
                    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="400" Width="500">
                        <Grid Name="panelTopGenres">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <toolkit:Chart Name="chartTopGenres" Title="Top Genres" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                   Margin="16,16,16,8" Padding="8" Background="White" >
                                <toolkit:BarSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" 
                           ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                           IsSelectionEnabled="False" Background="White"/>
                            </toolkit:Chart>
                            <Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="btnTopGenresToggle" Style="{StaticResource SmallButtonStyle}" 
            Content="Show All Genres" Width="120" 
            Margin="16,0,4,4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="btnToggle_Click" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </DockPanel>
            </Border>
        </DockPanel>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

> What can I do to make my chart fit the content rather than the other way around?

Get rid of any `StackPanels`:

```
<Grid Name="panelTopGenres">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <toolkit:Chart Name="chartTopGenres" Title="Top Genres" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                   Margin="16,16,16,8" Padding="8" Background="White" >
        <toolkit:BarSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" 
                           ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                           IsSelectionEnabled="False" Background="White"/>
    </toolkit:Chart>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="btnTopGenresToggle" Style="{StaticResource SmallButtonStyle}" 
            Content="Show All Genres" Width="120" 
            Margin="16,0,4,4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="btnToggle_Click" />
</Grid>
```

A `StackPanel` doesn't resize its children.

Comment: Didn't work for me, it still crushes all data into the default height without expanding.

Comment: What's the parent panel of the `Grid`? Please remember to always include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking a question.

Comment: OK, I've updated my original post to show the code for the whole window.  But however I structure my code I still can't seem to get the `Chart` to size properly.  Maybe I need a custom `DataTemplate`, but the examples I've seen look complex and I wouldn't know what bits to change.